# SQL Server - Reuse previous query - similar logic to Linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I am trying to write to achieve the logic of the following query:

```
select ......
from (select ..... from ... complex and long query #1) R1
     (select ..... from ... complex and long query #2) R2
Where
  NOT ( @DateStart > R2.IstEnde OR @DateEnd <= R2.IstStart)
OR 
(
    (select count(*) 
     from R2  // <---- BUG IS HERE
     Where R2.IsOutsideTaskTimeFrame = 1 AND R2.IsManuallyFixed = 1
    ) > 0
)
order BY R2.PersonName, R1.YearOfWeek, R1.Week
```

Which obvious do not work because I am trying to "Reuse" the R2 in the "count()" where condition.

I am writing this based on the ".NET Linq" logic where we can "reuse" the previous query.

Can I even write this logic of "reusing" the previous query and not repeating it again?

Comment: I'm not completely sure about that, but isn't "reusing" another word for a sql View concept?

Comment: how are you intending to join R1 and R2 there?  At the moment they have no join, or if there was a comma between them, then a CROSS JOIN (all rows to all rows)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for [CTE - Common Table Expression](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
;WITH R1 AS
(SELECT ...)
,R2 AS
(SELECT ...)
SELECT * FROM R1
... use R1 and R2 like any other table here (it's called "derived table")
```

If you need the result within independant queries, you might fill a declared table variable or a temp table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CTE to define a base query which can be used multiple times in the same scope of the code:

```
WITH Sales_CTE (returnParam1, returnParam2, ...)
AS
-- Define the CTE query.
(
    select ..... from ... complex and long query #2 
)
```

Or you can create a user defined function which gets params and returns the result, then call it multiple times:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ufnGetInventoryStock(param1 int, ...)  
RETURNS int   
AS    
RETURN ( 
    select ..... from ... complex and long query #2  
  )
```